# javascript confirm() is always true...whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, php

When I press okay, everything works fine so far. But when I press cancel, it does the exact thing that if I pressed okay...what's wrong with my code? :/

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['supprimer'])) { ?>   
    <script>var r = confirm('Etes-vous sur de vouloir supprimer?');
    if(r == true) { <?php $object->supprimer($_POST['rowID']); ?> 
    }</script> 
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `console.log(typeof(r), r);`

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/Rz2je/).

Comment: you can try if(r) instead if(r == true)

Comment: Add `<?php header('Content-Type: text/plain'); ?>` at the very top and then refresh your browser, take a look and read the code as the browser would "read" to execute it ... .

Comment: The way it works is like this: browser makes request `->` server receives request `->` server executes PHP `->` server sends response/HTML `->` browser receives response/HTML `->` browser parses HTML / executes JS

Comment: damn, well I guess it'll be more complicated than I thought..

Answer (score 15):

Your inner PHP script executes **regardless of the JavaScript conditional** since PHP runs before the page is rendered, thus, before JavaScript.  You would need to use ajax or a page reload in order to have PHP that runs on a conditional JavaScript statement.

Answer (score 3):

PHP runs before JavaScript.

```
$object->supprimer($_POST['rowID'])
```

is already submitted when browser load JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$supreme = 'yes';
if(isset($supreme)) { ?>
<script>
var r = confirm('Etes-vous sur de vouloir supprimer?');
alert(r);
if(r == true) { 
 alert('pressed Yes');
}
else
{alert('pressed Cancel');} 
</script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Try the above code - it will reflect the value chosen in the confirm popup.